# CSS filter property not working?

Tags: css, less

I'm following an blog post on displaying a "Loading" image when an Ajax call is being performed. The example has all of the styles inline and it works but I'm trying to convert it to having the CSS properties in an style sheet. Everything is converting just fine except for the filter property.

Here is the original code. The filter is in the main div and it is supposed to set the back ground of page to be transparent by 50% to draw attention to the Processing message.

```
<div id="divLoading" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; right: 0px;
    top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #666666; z-index: 30001;
    opacity: .8; filter: alpha(opacity=50); display:none">
    <p class="submit-progress" style="position: absolute; top: 30%; left: 45%; color: White;">
        Processing, please wait...<img src="~/images/ajax-loading.gif">
    </p>
</div>
```

This is the CSS I'm trying to convert it to.

```
.ajax-loading-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #666;
  z-index: 30001;
  opacity: .8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50) !important;
}

.ajax-loading-div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 7em;
  padding-top: 2.3em;

  width: 20em;
  margin-left: -10em;
  padding-left: 2.1em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.ajax-loading-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 20%;
  color: white;
}

.ajax-loading-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 39%;
  color: white;
}


<div id="divLoading" class="ajax-loading-wrapper" style="filter: alpha(opacity=50) !important;">
    <div class="ajax-loading-div">
        <span class="ajax-loading-text">
            Processing, please wait...
        </span>
        <span class="ajax-loading-icon fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I inspect the page I see that the filter property is crossed out. I tried adding the !Important but that didn't work. I also tried adding just the filter to the divLoading style and that doesn't work either. What I see with these setting is a small section (~25%) at the top of the page that has this background color but I'm needing it on the whole page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not quite how filter works (since IE8). It requires a list of filtering functions, each given a value. A working version of your example would be:

```
filter: opacity(0.5); // Opacity is 0 to 1, like the CSS property
```

Further Reading: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

Comment: Though it'd make more sense in this case to simply use `opacity: 0.5` if you don't require any further modification

Comment: Thanks for the info. I changed to filter: opacity(0.9); and that got me what I wanted. In the process I found my error with the height. I had the height set to 100px and not 100%. I also removed the opacity property since it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: That's strange that it didn't make a difference, the effects should stack. Glad that helped though.